# How to count event attendees with price sets and multiple bookings?

Tags: civievent, civireport

I am using price sets with events. In all the reports it has 'Fee Level' and it looks like this

Two Day Passes - 2,

I can count the number of people who registered, but not the number of passes sold except via, filter on 'Fee Level' and 'sed and awk'.

```
awk -F',' '{print $6 }' Report_20160905-720.csv | sed 's/"//g' | awk -F ' - ' '{sum+=$2} END {print sum}'
```

The fees section of the event is setup with price sets and field type 'number' which is the count. If I purchase 2x $30 passes the form calculates the amount. The reports however, have Two Day Passes - 2 and I can't see how to add up the actual number of passes bought, just the number of registrations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install Eileen's:
https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports

That will allow you to Filter for participants who have the 'Two Day Passes - 2' option.